# Samba: non-deletable directory in public share

Tags: samba, anonymous, smb-conf

I have this in `smb.conf`

```
[global]
security = user
guest account = nobody
map to guest = Bad User

[myshare]
path = /var/myshare
available = yes
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
force create mode = 0775
```

This allows anonymous access for users to myshare. I'd like to create a directory `/var/myshare/permanent` that users can't delete. Users should be able to create/modify/delete files and directories in `/var/myshare` and `/var/myshare/permanent`. Is this possible with anonymous access shares?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set the append attribute in linux.

```
# chattr +a permanent
```

In this case you can write into the directory but cannot delete it until you remove the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to disable unix-extension support(unix extension=no in [global field]), you can achieve it by enabling follow symlinks(follow symlinks=true) and use a symlink instead of a dir.

Answer (score 0):

In a directory with the sticky bit enabled, only the creator of a sub-directory can delete this sub-directory.

```
# chmod +t /var/myshare
# mkdir /var/myshare/permanent
# chown root:root /var/myshare/permanent
```

Only user `root` can delete `permanent`.